# Hibernate HQL statement returns 0 result instead of 1

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Working on my application on restrictions of what users can see.
Here are my classes I'm using :

```
User     Flux           MiniUsine
userID   fluxID         miniUsineID
fluxs    miniUsine      fluxs
         users          users
```

User <-> Flux is ManyToMany

Flux -> MiniUsine is ManyToOne

The statement i'm using is :

```
select mu
from MiniUsine mu
join mu.fluxs f
join f.users u
where u.userID = :id
```

This statement is giving me 0 results while I expect it to give one. Any idea about what's wrong in it ?

EDIT : My current data in the database are :

```
1 user with userID = 7
1 row in a table USERS_FLUXS with userID = 7 and FluxID = 102
1 flux with fluxID = 102 and miniUsineID = 1
1 miniUsine with miniUsineID = 1
```

This is why I expect one MiniUsine to be returned

Comment: Why you expect one?

Comment: My idea is that your expectation is wrong. But since you didn't say what the data are, what the code of the entities is, what the ID is, and what the code executing the query is, there's no way I can explain why.

Comment: @Jens, I expect one because I got one User which is related to one Flux which is related to one MiniUsine. The code works, the only problem is about the statement

Comment: Show sample data please

Comment: @Jens, Edited the post with data I expect to get back

Answer (score 0):

Check this query. Hope it may help you.

```
select mu
from MiniUsine as mu
inner join mu.fluxs as f
left outer join f.users as u
where u.userID = :id
```

Answer (score 0):

In HQL `join` is abbreviation for `inner join`, thus this query is transform to sql as query with `inner join`. So, if ther is not `fluxes` related to `MiniUsine` and no `User` relatet to `Flux` the result will be null.
You can try `left join`

```
select mu
from MiniUsine mu
left join mu.fluxs f
left join f.users u
where u.userID = :id
```